# Contains value pairs across two fields - Groovy

Tags: arrays, list, groovy, multiple-columns, contains

I have a data set with two fields: Department_ID and Vendor_ID. 
I want to flag any record where Department_ID equals a certain value and Vendor_ID equals a certain value. However, I have many pairs I'd like to flag. Without having to have a long script that repeats information redundantly, I want something short and easy.

Old logic:
${(DPT=='10'&& VND=='234' || DPT=='9'&& VND=='13' || DPT=='200'&& VND=='4987' || DPT=='598' && VND=='123')?"Yes":"NO"}

Preferred logic:
${['10','9','200','598'].contains(DPT)&&['234','13','4987','123'].contains(VND)?"Yes":"No"}

The issue with the preferred logic is that it would flag records that meet any combination of those values being present. ie, it would flag a record that had DPT=='10'&& VND=='13'... I need the contain feature but have it only look for certain pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for the presence of a pair:

```
${[['10', '234'], ['9', '13'], ['200', '4987'], ['598', '123']].contains([DPT, VND])?"Yes":"No"}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the pairs into a set and then check, if the set contains them.  E.g.

```
def known = [
    // DPT, VND
    ["10","123"],
    ["20","456"],
].toSet()

assert known.contains(["30","789"])==false
assert known.contains(["10","789"])==false
assert known.contains(["30","123"])==false
assert known.contains(["10","123"])==true
```